# ASP.NET WebApi 2.0 HttpResponseMessage cookies being cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got a project moving from MVC to WebApi 2. I have to occasionally set a cookie on the response from the webapi, so I wrote a class that extends OkNegotiatedContestResult,

```
   public class OkWithCookiesResult<T> : OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<HttpCookie> cookies;

        public OkWithCookiesResult(T content, IEnumerable<HttpCookie> cookies, ApiController controller)
            : base(content, controller)
        {
            this.cookies = cookies;
            foreach(var cookie in cookies)
            {
                cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host == "localhost" ? null : Request.RequestUri.Host;
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                cookie.Path = "/";
            }
        }

        public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

            response.Headers.AddCookies(cookies.Select(c => c.ToCookieHeaderValue()));

            return response;
        }     
    }
```

This is the ToCookieHeaderValue method,

```
    public static CookieHeaderValue ToCookieHeaderValue(this HttpCookie cookie) {
        CookieHeaderValue val = new CookieHeaderValue(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
        val.Expires = cookie.Expires;
        val.Domain = cookie.Domain;
        val.HttpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly;
        val.Path = cookie.Path;
        val.Secure = cookie.Secure;
        return val;
    }
```

Some debug code is left over in there, but you get the gist. My problem is the cookies I add to the header are cleared when the request is finished. I figured this out because I subscribed to the Application_EndRequest event, and the final response there has only one cookie, .ASPXAUTH with a null value. Is this left over from some FormsAuthentication thing from MVC?

Comment: Try to specify expire date

Comment: The ToCookieHeaderValue() does that, edited my post.